# How to set a property in a variable without starting a method?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to access the variable without entering a method, and would like to know if that's even possible.

I tried:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static ItemStack myItem = new ItemStack(Material.BOOK);
    myItem.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_DAMAGE, 1);
}
```

But I believe that isn't possible without starting a method (for example a main method)

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: No, it's not possible in Java. It's not valid in Java to have code outside of any methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about static initialization: [Static Initialization Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

```
public class MyClass{
    public static final ItemStack myItem = new ItemStack(Material.BOOK);
    static {
       myItem.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_DAMAGE, 1);
    }
}
```

Also this will work if your class is not final:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static final ItemStack myItem = new ItemStack(Material.BOOK) {

        {
            addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_DAMAGE, 1);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Also noteworthy that the second approach defines the anonymous class `MyClass$1`, which is suboptimal for most use cases.

Comment: suboptimal? yes. for most use cases... maybe, maybe. in most use cases it would be preemptive optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work out :

```
public class MyClass{
public static ItemStack myItem;
static
{ 
myItem = new ItemStack(Material.BOOK);
myItem.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_DAMAGE, 1);
}
}
```